# How to find the inverse of $f(x)=x+(-1)^{x-1}$

Tags: functions, exponential-function, inverse-function

> Question:
>
> Find the inverse of $f(x)=x+(-1)^{x-1}$ where $f:N\to N$ ($N$ denotes set of natural numbers)

Usually, when I am asked to find inverse of a given function, I use to express the dependant variable $x$ in terms of the independent variable $y$ as $x=g(y)$ where $g$ is a function, from the equation $y=f(x)$ where f is a function. Then I will replace $y$ by $x$ and $x$ by $f^{-1}(x)$, to get $f^{-1}x=g(x)$.

But in this problem, I am unable to do so. Is there any other method to find the inverse of such complex functions? How to find the inverse of the given function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be defined by $f(x)=x+(-1)^{x-1}$

If $x$ is odd, then $f(x)=x+1$, and if $x$ is even, then $f(x)=x-1$.

To invert $f$, just reverse the process . . .

If $x$ is even, then $f^{-1}(x)=x-1$, and if $x$ is odd, then $f^{-1}(x)=x+1$.

Thus, $f^{-1}(x)=f(x)$.

The basic idea when inverting a piecewise function is to invert each of the pieces.

Since $f$ maps the set of odd positive integers to the set of even positive integers by adding one, $f^{-1}$ maps the set of even positive integers to the set of odd positive integers by subtracting one.

Similarly, since $f$ maps the set of even positive integers to the set of odd positive integers by subtracting one, $f^{-1}$ maps the set of odd positive integers to the set of even positive integers by adding one.

Thus, $f^{-1}$ is also a piecewise function, and in this particular case, it turns out that $f^{-1}$ is the same as $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Try making a table and looking for a pattern.

$$\begin{array}{cc}
x&y\\
\hline
1&2\\
2&1\\
3&4\\
4&3\\
\vdots&\vdots
\end{array}$$

Do you see the pattern? Or maybe even, do you see what the inverse of $f$ is?

Comment: @GuruVishnu Perhaps you might calculate $f(f(x))$ for a few values of $x$

Comment: @Henry, Thanks for your response. Here it works fine, I am able to say the function and the inverse have same formula. But could you please give me a general approach which applies to all such complicated problems.

Comment: @GuruVishnu: There may not be a general approach.  For example $y=x + k^x$ has a similar form to yours  but for positive $k$ not equal to $1$, [Wolfram Alpha suggests a solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%3Dx%2Bk%5Ex) using the analytic continuation of the product log function

Comment: @Henry, Thank you Henry. I understood how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Show that $f(f(n))=n$ for all $ n \in \mathbb N.$ This gives: $f^{-1}=f.$